# Não Inserir Valores Iguais PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Eu tenho um script em PHP e MySQL que busca na tabela de clientes todos os clientes que não foram importados ainda para outro banco/tabela e importa.

Na tabela de clientes, tem uma `flag imported` com valores (0 ou 1).

Faço um select nela e importo para outro banco tabela.

Depois disso, no mesmo banco de dados que tem a tabela de clientes, tem uma tabela de logs onde é inserido o e-mail que foi importado e a data.

Só que as vezes ele coloca logs duplicados, como se tivesse importado duas vezes.

Eu não quero que ele ocorra o risco de importar ou na verdade inserir duas vezes o mesmo log.

Você pode perguntar, ah, basta coloca o campo e-mail como único.

Não posso fazer isso, porque meu sistema as vezes insere outros tipos de logs com e-mail do cliente então daria problema.

Qual seria melhor solução pra isso?

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar chave primária composta?
Leia sobre a mesma e se calhar para o seu projeto.
[Chave Primária Composta](http://www.luis.blog.br/chave-primaria-simples-e-chave-primaria-composta.aspx)

Comment: Poste a estrutura da sua tabela de log.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, você não passou a estrutura da tabela, mas caso precise de algum detalhe mais especifico, seria melhor posta essa parte.

Com o que tem, você pode fazer o seguinte para testar se existe email com o mesmo cliete e mesmo tipo de logo. Atere conforme sua necessidade.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM logs WHERE email ='joao@hotmail.com' and idcliente = 1 and idtipolog = 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO logs (idcliente, idtipolog , email ) VALUES(1,1, 'joao@hotmail.com');
END
```